# I am getting an error “Syntax error in Update statement” from code below:

Tags: vb.net

I am getting a syntax on this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub mysub()
        TextBox1.Text = "lol"
        then
        TextBox2.Text = "hi"
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is on then, pls help me.

Comment: Please take a moment to format you code!

Comment: why are you using **then**?

Comment: I see no Update statement in that code.  The error message you describe cannot possibly come from that code.  Please post the exact error message you are getting.  Also, get rid of Then in that code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, though I could guess, your code should look like:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub mysub()
        If TextBox1.Text == "lol"
        then
            TextBox2.Text = "hi"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your method:

```
Private Sub mysub()
    TextBox1.Text = "lol" then TextBox2.Text = "hi" 
End Sub
```

That doesn't compile because this statement does two things:

1. assigns a text to `TextBox1.Text`
2. executes an `Then` without an `If`

Of course you can use [`Then`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/752y8abs.aspx) only with an preceding `If`. I assume you want to do:

```
TextBox1.Text = "lol"
TextBox2.Text = "hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

the error here is with the `then`, which is used only in a `if` block;

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub mysub()
        TextBox1.Text = "lol"
        then  <-- error
        TextBox2.Text = "hi"
    End Sub
End Class
```

So either you remove the `then`, which will set the textbox1 and textbox2 values.
Or you add a condition, as;

```
 If TextBox1.Text = "lol" then  
    TextBox2.Text = "hi"
 End If
```